# How to sort the latitude and longitude points so that when creating a polygon, lines do not intersect

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am working in the google map to show 4 markers and a polygon to join these 4 markers as a marker but the code I have tried giving me some kind of two triangle polygon(the lines are cross connected). How can I fix the code so that these lines do not cross connect.

```js
function initMap() {
  var beaches = [
    ["a", 40.4476, -83.0767],
    ["b", 40.3655, -83.0441],
    ["d", 40.5943, -83.0128],
    ["e", 40.5113, -82.6063]
  ];
  var triangleCoords = [{
      lat: 40.4476,
      lng: -83.0767,
      'name': 'n'
    },
    {
      lat: 40.3655,
      lng: -83.0441,
      'name': 'n'
    },
    {
      lat: 40.5943,
      lng: -83.0128,
      'name': 'n'
    },
    {
      lat: 40.5113,
      lng: -82.6063,
      'name': 'n'
    }
  ];

  function SortByName(x, y) {
    return ((x.name == y.name) ? 0 : ((x.name > y.name) ? 1 : -1));
  }
  triangleCoords.sort(SortByName);
  var polygroups = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < triangleCoords.length; i++) {
    var groupName = triangleCoords[i].name;
    if (!polygroups[groupName]) {
      polygroups[groupName] = [];
    }
    polygroups[groupName].push({
      lat: triangleCoords[i].lat,
      lng: triangleCoords[i].lng
    });
  }
  var markers = [];
  var map;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {
      lat: 40.5943,
      lng: -83.0128
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker, i;
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  var count = 0;
  $.each(polygroups, function(i, value) {
    var users = {
      0: {
        color: '#f45942'
      },
      1: {
        color: '#f4df41'
      },
      2: {
        color: '#58f441'
      }
    }
    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: value,
      strokeColor: users[count].color,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      fillColor: users[count].color,
      fillOpacity: 0.0
    });
    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
    count++;
  });

  for (i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(beaches[i][1], beaches[i][2]),
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBA6r9FMT7APwfx0OfOKj8IZwq9gkCPN-I&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

You have listed them in the wrong order...

```
  var triangleCoords = [{
    lat: 40.4476,
    lng: -83.0767,
    'name': 'n'
  }, {
    lat: 40.3655,
    lng: -83.0441,
    'name': 'n'
  }, {
    lat: 40.5113,
    lng: -82.6063,
    'name': 'n'
  }, {
    lat: 40.5943,
    lng: -83.0128,
    'name': 'n'
  }];
```

Gives you a square...

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cmjcs5eL/20/

Comment: i have to make order based on asc lat?

Comment: No, The order of the list is the order in which the markers are added. Provided they follow after each other in the line you want they can be all over the place: https://jsfiddle.net/cmjcs5eL/22/ Array is reversed and still a polygone square is drawn as they all still follow each other

Comment: those datas are from database result and i provide only four dummy for this question. So how can i know which point follow which.

Comment: That is the problem you have to solve ;) I have no idea what you are trying to achieve, I just answered the question you asked. :)